# XStreamMarshaller ignore unknown elements

Tags: spring, xstream

After change data model on server side my XStream client throw Exception

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field {fieldName}

To prevent this behavior I try to do something to ignore unknown elements. 
I am using XStreamMarshaller from Spring-oxm 4.0.5 and XStream 1.4.5. I known that since XStream version 1.4.5 is available method ignoreUnknownElements().

```
XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    marshaller.setStreamDriver(streamDriver);
    marshaller.setAutodetectAnnotations(autodetectAnnotations);
    marshaller.getXStream().ignoreUnknownElements();
```

Above solution doesn't work and I still get mentioned exception.

I have client side model copied from server. 
For example:

```
public class Device implements Serializable {

    protected String device_id;

    protected String device_model_code;

    protected String device_model_name;

    protected String device_name;

//getters, setters
}
```

If I comment field for example device_model I will have Exception

com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field device_name

How can I solve my problem? How can I implement XStreamMarshaller to ignore unknown elements?

Comment: Can you include your datamodel and highlight the recent change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is that method ignoreUnknownElements() available since XStream 1.4.5 is only for marshaling not for unmarshaling. So it doesn't work if somebody adds a new field in data model on server side.

To solve described problem you have to override protected method constructXStream() from org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller implementation:

```
public class CustomXStreamMarshaller extends XStreamMarshaller {

@Override
protected XStream constructXStream() {
    // The referenced XStream constructor has been deprecated as of 1.4.5.
    // We're preserving this call for broader XStream 1.4.x compatibility.
    return new XStream() {
        @Override
        protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
                return new MapperWrapper(next) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSerializeMember(Class definedIn, String fieldName) {
                        if (definedIn == Object.class) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return super.shouldSerializeMember(definedIn, fieldName);
                    }
                };
        }
    };
}}
```

You only need to use your own implementation in XStreamMarshaller declaration:

```
CustomXStreamMarshaller marshaller = new CustomXStreamMarshaller();
    marshaller.setStreamDriver(streamDriver);
    marshaller.setAutodetectAnnotations(autodetectAnnotations);
```

Comment: ignoreUnknownElements() IS for unmarshalling and has the expected result for me of skipping over XML tags that are not mappable. If you look at the source code for AbstractReflectionConverter, you will note that UnknownFieldException is thrown when unmarshalling data - not when marshalling it. It is not obvious to me what the code above is intended to do or how it solves the problem indicated. That said, it also isn't clear to me why the OP was experiencing the exception - would need to see more info including the XML being unmarshalled.